# How to add Double.Parse

Tags: vb.net, parsing, double

I am trying to display a `TextChanged` result but I have an error that says:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.`

Here is my sample code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim double1 As Double = 0.0
Dim double2 As Double = 0.0
Dim result As Double = 0.0
Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    double1 = TextBox1.Text
    double2 = TextBox2.Text
    result = Double.Parse(Label1.Text).ToString

    result = double1 + double2
End Sub
```

I am new to this stuff. How will I fix this? Thank you for the response.

Comment: That wont even compile using `Option Strict`.  If `double1` is a double, you cant just assign text to it.  Rather than `Double.Parse`, you should use **[Double.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)** to catch illegal characters.  Then you can add the duly converted doubles

Comment: Let me try this one. Thank you, @Plutonix.

Comment: That is some seriously crazy code. Maybe you should try explaining what you are trying to achieve. My guess would be that the user is supposed to enter two numbers into those `TextBoxes` and then you want to add them and display the result in the `Label`. If so then, among other things, you need to send output TO the `Label`, not get data FROM it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney you are technically right. That's what I'm trying to explain here.

Comment: Many beginners can't write code to do what they want because they don't know what they want. They have an idea of the start point and the end point but they don't really think about the specific steps in between so they can't write code to implement those steps. You should pick up a pen and paper and write down what those elementary steps are.  Once you have that list, start writing code to implement them one by one.  Your list of steps would start something like this: get text from `TextBox1`, parse it to a `Double`. Immediately there's an issue with your code as there's no parsing.

Comment: Are you sure you want this code in the Text_Changed event? That fires with every keystroke. Why not wait until the user is finished with the entry and then clicks a button to calculate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use both "IF" or the val to get you around your issue. And you're not showing anything in the label that way. You need to have it>
`Label1.text = result` to show it.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

        'If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) OrElse Not IsNumeric(TextBox2.Text) Then Exit Sub

        Dim double1 As Double
        Dim double2 As Double
        Dim result As Double

        double1 = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        double2 = Val(TextBox2.Text)

        result = double1 + double2
        Label1.Text = result

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. You will avoid sneaky runtime errors. Double.TryParse is preferable to the old VB6 Val or IsNumeric.